# String to numeric conversion in c#

Tags: c#, string, numbers

I am trying to write a function to convert the contents of a `string` "12345" to an `int`.

If the string is blank i would like to return `null` (uninitialized), not the value `0`.

Problem is, functions do not return un-initialized values.

My code will not compile as Retval can return an uninitialized value......

My attempt so far:

```
public int ConvertStringToNumber(String TheString)
{
    // Uninitialized
    int Retval;

    if (TheString.Length > 0)
    {
        // We have a valid string
        if (Int32.TryParse(TheString, out Retval))
        {
            // We have a valid Number
        }
    }

    // Return the number or null
    return Retval;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you use Nullable int ? it will allow set as nullable . See here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11854/C-2-0-Nullable-Types

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nullable int (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

> Nullable types can represent all the values of an underlying type, and
>   an additional null value.

```
public int? ConvertStringToNumber(String TheString)
{
    int retval;
    bool isInt = Int32.TryParse(TheString, out retval);
    return isInt ? retval : null;
}
```

Note: When using nullable types, you'll need to use a cast or get it's value. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

**Example:**

```
int? n = ConvertStringToNumber("123");

int value = n.Value;
// or
int value = (int)n;
```

Answer (score 0):

since `Int32.TryParse(TheString, out Retval)` require int type not nullable

```
public int? ConvertStringToNumber(String TheString)
{

    // Uninitialized
    int Retval;

    if (TheString.Length > 0)
    {

        // We have a valid string

        if (Int32.TryParse(TheString, out Retval))
        {

            // We have a valid Number
            return Retval;
        }

    }

            // Return the number or null

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assigned a value to the Retval object AT THE FIRST TIME, then the value is valid in THAT area ONLY. 
So, Retval is null when you return it.

Answer (score -1):

Simple extension method to resolve your problem

```
using System;

namespace temp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string valu = "";
            Console.WriteLine(valu.ToInt32());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public static class MyExtentions
    {
        public static int ToInt32(this string s)
        {
            int x;
            if (s != null)
            {
                if (s.Length > 1)
                    x = Convert.ToInt32(s);
                else
                    x = 0;
            }
            else
            {
               x= 0;
            }
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int? x = ConvertStringToNumber("1");
```

int value = x.Value;

String to numeric conversion in c#